# Can't get a button to bring up a new activity

Tags: android, button

I'm quite new to programming and have just hit a simple road block that is holding me up.  I am trying to have a button from my main activity call up another activity.  I've researched but as yet I haven't found something to work (probably really simple and stupid).  Any help would be appreciated.  I've included the code for my main activity.  Thank you

```
package com.example.valentinetimer;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class CardFront extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = null;

    Button openButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardfrontxml);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    //Button
    openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openButton);
    openButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.cardfrontxml);
    this.openButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.openButton);
    this.openButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Click Event");

            Intent intent = new Intent (null, CardContent.class);
            startActivity (intent);
        }
    });
    //End Button

}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:          Unable to find explicit activity class   {com.example.valentinetimer/com.example.valentinetimer.CardContent}; have you declared this   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1504)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1382)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3095)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3201)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at com.example.valentinetimer.CardFront$1.onClick(CardFront.java:42)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-08 10:18:51.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2494):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: setting `openButton` twice? two different `onClick()`?? odd

Comment: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? `????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your CardContent class is not specified in your manifest correctly. Please add this to your manifest in the application tag:

```
<activity
    android:name=".CardContent">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (null, CardContent.class);
```

use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (CardFront.this, CardContent.class);
```

Another mistake that is causing you a "null pointer",
you are trying to use "findViewById" before calling "setContentView",
you must call "setContentView" before trying to access anything that has to do with the layout of the activity. a good practice will be to put it right after "super.onCreate" line.

Another thing, change the TAG to have actual string value and not Null.

*Edit after seeing the log cat:*
the second activity should also be declared in your manifest. add it there.

Comment: Thank you but it is giving me a null pointer exception.

Comment: Please post the null pointer exception.

Comment: I've added the logcat text

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I thought I had setContentView after super.onCreate.  Am I missing something (I probably am mind you).

Comment: Try the latest edit: add the second activity to manifest

Comment: I will in just a moment.  Let you know.

Comment: That did the trick.  My apologies for the stupid question. Thank you for your help.